# Converse of Enstrom-Kakeya theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

If the coefficients of the polynomial $p(z):=\sum_0^n a_i z^i$ are nonnegative,does the converse of Enstrom-Kakeya theorem hold true. That is, if all the roots are known to lie in the unit disc under the said assumption,does it follow that the coefficients must be in decreasing order? Thank you for any help/hints/suggestions

Comment: $$f(x)=3x^3+5x^2+4x+1$$ is a counterexample.

Comment: For another counterexample, try $p(z)=(z+{\large{\frac{3}{4}}})^4$.

Comment: Thank you for the example in the answer.if the  coefficients are in increasing order,will all the roots lie outside?kindly clarify

Comment: If the (positive) coefficients are strictly increasing , the roots must all have absolute value greater than $1$ , this is a variant of Enestrom-Kakeya.